# How to filter object and return only key value if key is uppercase

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

```js
 var params = {
  "rn": "AuditTrailLogon",
  "Dateange": "lastquarter",
  "App": "20000",
  "ts": "AuditTrailLogon"   
}
    
    
      let filtered = Object.keys(params)
       .filter(key => key.toUpperCase() === key);  

    console.log("filtered", filtered);
```

How can I filter the object and return only the ones that are uppercase keys

```
var params = {
  "rn": "AuditTrailLogon",
  "Dateange": "lastquarter",
  "App": "20000",
  "ts": "AuditTrailLogon"   
}
```

Tried .filter method but it return null

```
let filtered = Object.keys(params )
  .filter(key => key.toUpperCase() === key);

console.log("filtered", filtered);  returns null []
```

how to get

```
{
   "Dateange": "lastquarter",
   "App": "20000",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the key to Uppercase, so when you compare the keys you get something like this:`APP === App`, but if you want to compare the keys just by the first character of the key capitalized, you can do something like this:

```
let filtered = Object.keys(params )
      .filter(key => {
        let capitalizedKey = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);
         return capitalizedKey === key
      });
```

Comment: that was it, I somehow thought, uppercase only the first character

Answer (score 2):

Convert the object to entries (`Object.entries()`), filter the entries(I've used a regex), and then convert back to object with `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const params = {
  "rn": "AuditTrailLogon",
  "Dateange": "lastquarter",
  "App": "20000",
  "ts": "AuditTrailLogon"
}

const uppercaseTest = /^[A-Z]/

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(params)
    .filter(([key]) => uppercaseTest.test(key))
)

console.log(result)
```